# For each row, identify the proportion of columns that have the same value in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset of survey responses similar to this:

```
toy <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3), v2 = c(1,6,3), v3 = c(1,2,4), v4 = c(1,7,3))

toy
  v1 v2 v3 v4
1  1  1  1  1
2  2  6  2  7
3  3  3  4  3
```

I want to detect "straightlining" by finding the most common value for each row and calculating the proportion of columns with that value.

Two examples:

- if the value of every column in a row is 5, then the new variable should return 1
- If the value of 60% of the columns in a row is 3 and 40% of the columns is 4, then the variable should return .6

Desired output:

```
  v1 v2 v3 v4 straightline_pct
1  1  1  1  1   1
2  2  6  2  7 .50
3  3  3  4  3 .75
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One base approach:

```r
toy <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3), v2 = c(1,6,3), v3 = c(1,2,4), v4 = c(1,7,3))

toy$straightline_pct = apply(as.matrix(toy),
                             1L,
                             function (x) max(prop.table(table(x)))
                             )

toy
#>   v1 v2 v3 v4 straightline_pct
#> 1  1  1  1  1             1.00
#> 2  2  6  2  7             0.50
#> 3  3  3  4  3             0.75
```

Answer (score 3):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

toy <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,3), v2 = c(1,6,3), v3 = c(1,2,4), v4 = c(1,7,3))

toy %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(perc = table(c_across(everything())) %>% 
      {(ncol(toy) - length(.) + 1) / ncol(toy)}) %>% ungroup

#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>      v1    v2    v3    v4  perc
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     1     1  1   
#> 2     2     6     2     7  0.5 
#> 3     3     3     4     3  0.75
```

---

An alternative, based on `ave` function:

```
toy %>%
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(perc = c_across(1:4) %>%
    {max(ave(., ., FUN=length)) / ncol(toy)}) %>% ungroup
```

Answer (score 3):

Slight variation with just `table`

```
toy$straightline_pct <- apply(toy, 1, function(x) max(table(x))/length(x) )
toy
  v1 v2 v3 v4 straightline_pct
1  1  1  1  1             1.00
2  2  6  2  7             0.50
3  3  3  4  3             0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

I like @Paul Smith's and @Cole's answers better, but for completeness here's a more verbose approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
toy %>%
  bind_cols(toy %>%
      mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
      pivot_longer(-row) %>%
      count(row, value) %>%
      group_by(row) %>%
      mutate(straightline_pct = n / sum(n)) %>%
      slice_max(straightline_pct) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      select(straightline_pct)
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and verbose solution that is largely similar to other answers already:

```
library(tidyverse)
toy %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    straightline_pct = max(table(c_across(everything()))) / ncol(.)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
     v1    v2    v3    v4 straightline_pct
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>            <dbl>
1     1     1     1     1             1   
2     2     6     2     7             0.5 
3     3     3     4     3             0.75
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can turn your data into a matrix first:

```
toy <- data.matrix(toy)
storage.mode(toy) <- "integer"
```

Then with the help of `matrixStats`:

```
library(matrixStats)

rowMaxs(rowTabulates(toy)) / ncol(toy)
[1] 1.00 0.50 0.75
```